# manually exclude some symbols from [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

The code below will remove all symbols from myString.  Is there a shortest way to make some exclusive symbols (say ')from being removed while still be able to use this code?

```
myString = [[myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a mutable copy and then make changes using the [`NSMutableCharacterSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *mcs = [[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet] mutableCopy];
[mcs removeCharactersInString:@"<characters you want excluded>"];

myString = [[myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:mcs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

[mcs release];
```